Could there be another relative language of the ancient Egyptian language closer to it than the Coptic?
The standard position in Egyptology is that the ancient Egyptian language was lost and that its closest relative was the Coptic, how could this conclusion have been reached in the early period of Egyptology even before the time of Champollion in the early 1800s? Was there any systematic studies of languages across Africa and elsewhere to see if they are related to the Coptic and thus its parent language?

The short answer is that Coptic is Egyptian! They're so closely related because they're one and the same.
Generally, the term "Egyptian" is used for any stage of the language written in hieroglyphs, hieratic, or demotic script, and "Coptic" is used for any stage of the language written in a Greek-derived script. But both of those terms cover an enormous span of time. The later forms of "Egyptian" are extremely similar to the earlier forms of "Coptic", much more than they are to the earlier forms of "Egyptian"—language changes a lot over a few thousand years.
And this fact is actually how hieroglyphs were first deciphered: by comparing them against Coptic. A particular name in a cartouche had to mean, from context, "Thoth is born"; in Coptic, "newborn" is mas; Greek records recorded a pharaoh named Thutmose. Therefore the second half of that name is probably the consonants m-s, and so on!

In a similar vein, one could claim that the modern Romance languages are Latin. They are very different, but they are also very similar. There is a clear history from one to the other (Romance languages are largely Vulgar Latin influenced by Germanic, Celtic, and Slavic languages) and there was no specific date where people in Gaul went to bed speaking Latin and got up the next morning speaking French.

Is that you, Champollion?

By analogy, OP’s question is like “Could there be another relative of classical Latin, closer to it than Italian?”  As such, the main answer “No — modern Italian is a direct descendant, and which is as close as you can get”, since in linguistics “close” is understood primarily as meaning closeness of descent. However, one can reasonably also consider “closeness” in the sense of shared properties of grammar, phonology, etc — which roughly amounts to asking which of the descendants of Latin is most conservative; and in this sense, the answer is arguably “Yes — Sardinian!” [cont’d

since most sources I can find suggest Sardinian is more conservative than standard Italian.  As such, this answer gives the main part of an answer to OP’s question, but isn’t quite the end of the story — one should at least consider the question of whether there are any other direct descendants of ancient Egyptian, which might be more conservative (which is I guess the scenario OP had in mind).

@PLL The trick is that all descendants of Egyptian—and there are several!—are called "Egyptian" if written in hieroglyphs and "Coptic" if not. Sahidic, Bohairic, Lycopolitan, etc.

Both of you grossly misinterpreted the question. A better analogy would be asking whether there could be another relative of Proto-Hellenic, closer to it than Greek. To respond with Draconis that Modern Greek is a form of Greek written in Latin and Ancient Greek a form written in Greek is utter nonsense, generalia aren't specific enough (in general you write good answers, ironically speaking). To respond with PLL that Latin is a better model suffers from the same basic problem. What one wants to know is a hypthetical framework and unexpected results, like Mycenaen Greek, ...

which was barely hypothetical up to the discovery of Linear B; or pre-Greek, which remains hypothetical and so unclear if it could be related to Proto-Hellenic at all.

In the Romance framework, equivalently, one could point to Venetian and the theories of a non-Latin Italic ancestor; Dalmation, etc.

@vectory With all due respect, your analogies make no sense. "Modern Greek is a form of Greek written in Latin and Ancient Greek a form written in Greek" is utter nonsense. The dividing line between "Egyptian" and "Coptic" is defined orthographically, since that provides an easy cutoff point to use. But since hieroglyphic-derived writing and Greek-derived writing coexisted for some time, there's no fundamental syntactic, phonological, morphological, etc difference that can distinguish late Egyptian from early Coptic.

@Draconis, "no sense" is a bit much. It's not the main thrust of my argument.

you might reasonably complain that the fringe theory about Venetion is not based on Italic but Balkans, for lack of a better word. That's an honest omission.

It seems from my research that it is unanimously agreed that Coptic is, as a direct descendant, the closest to Egyptian.
Other than that, the closest languages are either the Chadic languages (still spoken) or Akkadian (extinct?).
As to your theory that we might have missed a couple of other languages, I would say that if they did, they would be so small and with the growth of communication, had to have died out quickly.
Hope this helps.

AIUI, the general consensus is that the Egyptian and Semitic branches of the Afroasiatic language family diverged before the split into East and West Semitic, which would make all Semitic languages (including still spoken Arabic, Hebrew, Aramaic and Amharic) as closely related to Egyptian as Akkadian is.

But is not Akkadian Semitic?

@MufarridAnsari Yes, it’s East Semitic. Afro-Asiatic first split into (among others) Egyptian and Semitic. Then later on, Semitic split into East and West Semitic. Then later on East Semitic split into individual, attested languages,  one of them being Akkadian. So all the Semitic languages are as closely related to Egyptian as each other. Think of it like a family tree: you are Akkadian, your mother is East Semitic, and your grandmother is Semitic. Egyptian is your grandmother’s sister. You’re no more closely related to your grandmother’s sister than any of your siblings or cousins are.

@JanusBahsJacquet Though there is also the element of time difference—we could say Latin is as distant from Faliscan as French is, because their point of separation is the same, but French is much more different because it's had a few thousand more years to evolve. (In this case, I don't know how much that really matters, because estimates put the split between Egyptian and PS like 15,000 years ago, but might help the answerer's understanding.)

Going by the answers, can It be known what other languages across the world may be considered as descendants of Ancient Egyptian like the Coptic? Are there well-known studies in this regard? If there are other languages then the question of which may be more conservative may now be asked.
